# How to display selected file names with openfiledialog on datagridview in WindowsForms C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, windows-forms-designer, openfiledialog

I set a list as the datasource of my DGV. I want to select files and then add names and formats of selected files under a certain column on DGV, adding rows for each file.
I have googled so far, but all answers are for data which is given 'by the user', for example a person's name and age are given by the user. However, what I need is that the program reads information(name and format) without any input by the user.

Any help is welcomed and appreciated!

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Dokument auswählen
{
 
   OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Filter = "Word(*.docx)| *.docx|PPT(*.pptx)|*.pptx|PDF(*.pdf)|*.pdf|Alle Dateien(*.*)|*.*";
            ofd.Multiselect = true;
            List<DateienList> dateienlist = new List<DateienList>();
            
                if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                {
                   //Don't know what to do here.
                }
   }           

private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {    
            BindingList<DateienList> myList = new BindingList<DateienList>();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = myList;  //Datasource set    
        }

class DateienList //datasource, the list
    {
        [DisplayName("Dateiennamen")]
        public string Dateiennamen { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Neue Dateiennamen")]
        public string Neue_Dateiennamen { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Anzahl Kopien")]
        public int Anzahl_Kopien { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Umlaut Entfernen")]
        public bool Umlaut_Entfernen { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("PDF Erzeugen")]
        public bool PDF_Erzeugen { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Wasserzeichen Hinzufügen")]
        public bool Waasserzeichen_Hinzufügen { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Throw that `dataGridView1_CellContentClick_1` away

Comment: @CaiusJard thanks, I did not understand the structure of code in general, so I thought that should be done when cell's clicked...

Comment: Indeed, you probably don't want to re-bind your DGV to an empty list any time the user clicks on a cell in the grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Dokument auswählen
        {
            //This should be done in Form load event
            BindingList<DateienList> myList = new BindingList<DateienList>();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = myList;  //Datasource set    

            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Filter = "Word(*.docx)| *.docx|PPT(*.pptx)|*.pptx|PDF(*.pdf)|*.pdf|Alle Dateien(*.*)|*.*";
            ofd.Multiselect = true;
            List<DateienList> dateienlist = new List<DateienList>();

            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                //Loop the files selected from dialog, and find information here.
                foreach (var item in ofd.FileNames)
                {
                    DateienList tmp= new DateienList();
                    tmp.Dateiennamen = item;
                    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(item);
                    if (fileInfo.Extension.ToLower().Equals(".pdf"))
                    {
                        tmp.PDF_Erzeugen = true;
                        tmp.Umlaut_Entfernen = false;
                        tmp.Waasserzeichen_Hinzufügen = false;
                    } 
                    // check for other file types
                    myList.Add(tmp);
                }
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for such a kind explanation. It works! However, I did not really understand the part:  if (fileInfo.Extension.ToLower().Equals(".pdf")) What does it do?

Comment: it just checks the file extension and make sure the extension is case insensitive, like , test.pdf is pdf file type, while test.PDF and test.Pdf are also pdf file type.